# Prevent Summary Band from appearing alone on a new page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a simple report that consists of a Detail and a Summary bands.

Sometimes, the number of rows in the detail makes the summary appear alone on the next page and my customer does not like that.

There probably is a classical solution to this problem but could not find it.

Is it possible to get some contextual information about the y-position of some elements in order to add some page break?

Up to now, the only "solution" I get is to generate 2 reports :

1. a "normal" report.
2. a second report where I add a rectangle which takes 90% of the page height just before the summary.

Then, if the 2 reports have the same number of pages, I detect that the summary line is alone on its page. Then I can generate a 3rd report where I introduce a page break at line "nbRows - 5"...

This "solution" is not satisfying at all XD.

Comment: `This "solution" is not satisfying at all XD.` - And what is a right hypothetical solution of your customer (to decrease the height of pages, to add some fake text, to increase font, ..)? What kind of solution prefer your customer?

Comment: You can try to replace Summary with Group Footer (for fake group). This band has different useful features.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my reports.
One of the solution is to put the -> isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" in JasperReport tag.

**Example :**

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Usage-receipt" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="0" isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" uuid="e9bb1a27-f975-4aa4-98f9-75524c5daafa">
```